# Grok filter with spaces and unpredictable logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok

I am trying to set up some grok filters to pull my firewall logs into Elastic.

The issue i am experiencing is the logs are unpredictable and some fields have spaces which i cant figure out how to match.

So with the log

`<140>May 10 08:00:00 FW-Firewal-1 SN123456789 (2023-05-10T08:00:00) firewall: msg_id="3000-0148" Allow INTERNET Client-LAN 52 tcp 20 126 192.168.1.1 192.168.2.1 50713 445 offset 8 S 417387653 win 61690 (My-Firewall-Policy)`

my following grok pattern works fine

```
%{INT:syslog_pri}>%{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME:time} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} %{WORD:serial_number} \(%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\) %{NOTSPACE:process} msg_id="%{DATA:msg_id}" %{WORD:action} %{WORD:src_network} %{WORD:dst_network} %{NUMBER:packet_length:int} %{NOTSPACE:protocol} %{NUMBER:metric:int} %{NUMBER:ttl:int} %{IP:source_ip} %{IP:destination_ip} %{NUMBER:source_port:int} %{NUMBER:destination_port:int} %{WORD} %{INT} %{WORD} %{INT} %{WORD} %{INT} %{GREEDYDATA:rule_name}
```

The issue i have is these logs can vary, and an example of this is the src_network and dst_network can often be multiple words. E.G Client LAN instead of Client-LAN. In these cases my filter obviously doesn't match them. Im struggling to find a way to match the string if it includes a space.